# Dump process's stdin and stdout

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, command-line

I have two processes, let's say Parent and Child. Parent launches the Child and communicates with it through child's stdin and stdout.

```
Parent <-> Child
```

These processes use text protocol and I need to investigate it. I would like to create a bash script which will be launched by the Parent instead of child. This script will launch the Child and in addition will dump stdin and stdout streams to a log files.

```
Parent <-> MyProcess <-> Child
            |
            v
          log.txt
```

Is there a way in bash to do what I need or do I need to use C?

Comment: Do you know about `tee`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to use `tee` to dump the input to and output from the child to two separate files like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
tee in.log | child | tee out.log
```

You could use `tee`'s `-a` parameter (*append*) to write both logs to the same file, but I'm not quite sure if they'll be interleaved in the right order or just written one after the other:

```
#!/bin/bash
tee -a both.log | child | tee -a both.log
```

Comment: Great code! I'm impressed. This is nearly what I need. On some reason child process exits immediately in this situation. I guess that's because parent is writing to a stdout of bash, but not stdout of tee. I do not know how to check this.

Comment: This shouldn't change the behavior of the child process at all... Does the parent process pass any arguments to the child? If so, did you add them to the child invocation in the script? Another reason I can imagine is that tee might be buffering the stdin/stdout until it receives a newline character, thereby tripping some kind of timeout in the child process (though that seems unlikely, since you say the child is terminating immediately).

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake of mine. This script works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

If you use named pipes, then it doesn't matter if you have child and parent processes:

p1:

```
#!/bin/sh
# p1

rm -f p1.fifo;mkfifo p1.fifo
trap "exit 1"  0 1 2 3 13 15

while read line; do
    echo p1 got "$line"
    echo p1 sending $line to p2
    echo $line > p2.fifo
    sleep 1
done < p1.fifo
```

p2:

```
#!/bin/sh
# p2

rm -f p2.fifo;mkfifo p2.fifo
trap "exit 1"  0 1 2 3 13 15

while read line; do
    echo p2 got "$line"
    echo p2 sending $line to p1
    echo $line > p1.fifo
    sleep 1
done < p2.fifo
```

inital message:

```
echo message > p1.fifo
```

the output of p1:

```
p1 got message
p1 sending message to p2
p1 got message
p1 sending message to p2
```

the output of p2:

```
p2 got message
p2 sending message to p1
p2 got message
p2 sending message to p1
p2 got message
```